# SWRevealViewController and TableView - swipe to delete not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe, swrevealviewcontroller

I added the SWRevealViewController to my app, along with the hamburger stack to access my menu. My app has a UITableView for the main application view. I want to allow users to delete items from the list using the swipe to delete function.

I enabled the swipe to delete and added a method call to handle this. I noticed that the method never gets called. Not sure how to get this to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was asked for a code example. I have not made any changes to the SWRevealViewController standard source code. In my code for the TableView, I have added the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Normally, the code above should show a delete button when you do a right to left swipe. However, this is not happening. My guess is that the SWRevealViewController is eating the pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: If you post your code, it will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Try using this. Super easy https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Comment: Never mind. I figured this out by calling the following from viewDidLoad:

    SWRevealViewController *reveal = self.revealViewController;
    reveal.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

Answer (score 4):

Just found a solution after reading a thread of a guy asking a similar question to the maker of this class.  Whatever class you use to add the gesture recognizers, make it the delegate of the SWRevealController then paste in this method.

```
#pragma mark - SWRevealViewControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController
{
    float velocity = [revealController.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view].x;
    if (velocity < 0 && self.revealViewController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPositionLeft)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: @JohnKakon i have tried this but not working can you tell me how it is working?

Comment: @Nisha When you swipe from right to the left `SWRevealViewController` receives touch event instead of `TableViewController`. This code prevents the receiving and allows TableViews' cells to work normally. In which class did you add this code? It should be controller that extends `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate`, not `UITableViewController`. Also you can check that method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool` is implemented in your `UITableViewController`

Comment: @JohnKakon thanks for reply. ya Instead of tableview SWRevealViewController receives touch. Now i have done solution in my way.

Answer (score 2):

I have done like this < UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in .h file in which you are implementing tableview cell delete functionality and in .m file viewDidLoad

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];        
self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

After that simply use this method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"])
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
}
```