# Slide to delete UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using **SWRevealViewController** for side menu. The loaded UIViewController contains a UITableView. The table view had slide to delete enabled. However, the edit functionality does not work always. i.e, **tableView: commitEditingStyle:** does not get fired. Although it happens after several tries. I believe there is a conflict in gesture recogniser. Have been at it for a day now. Can somebody help me out here?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [self.shopListArray count];
    if (row < count) {
        [[[self.shopListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:IFRecipe_ingredient]  removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    }
    [self.shopListTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

What do I do when there is a conflict in gestures?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SWRevealViewController willn't work will UISlider too :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` in your code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

and Problem with Pan gesture recogniser in SWRevealViewController, in superview contain pan gesture recogniser we get tableview swibe recognizer issue in view , remove Pan gesture in SWRevealViewController and check.

Comment: This is the default if not implemented.

Comment: I have used this as well. But in vain. The above code works fine if i'm not using SWRevealViewController.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable edit mode for table view, you can call edit method on UITableView as,
in `viewdidload` or in `viewwillappear`

```
// try this

[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

then after u can easily do that.

Comment: But in the above case. It shows the minus sign in the cell. I want to implement slide to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

At first make tableview editing mode YES on your did load method or when required.

`[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25987204/4376612 post.Solved my problem. Have to use the following code,

```
- (BOOL)revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController
{
    float velocity = [revealController.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view].x;
    if (velocity < 0 && self.revealViewController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPositionLeft)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```