# SWRevealViewController issue-Drawer is open,when scrolling frontviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController.Problem is that when i am scrolling tableview or swipe tableview (on frontviewcontroller),drawer is open.Means PanGestureRecognizer is fire when i am scroll the tableview.I have tried the lot of things but not get the solution.Please help me to provide the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319940/swrevealviewcontroller-and-tableview-swipe-to-delete-not-working for your issue may this help you.

Comment: can you please provide some code...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried this but it is not working.I used updated (new SWRevealViewController library) SWRevealViewController class and my issue has resolved.

Comment: can you upload some code

Comment: on selection the row from left drawer i used the following code-                                                      FeaturedIndustryVC *objFeaturedIndustryVC=[[FeaturedIndustryVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FeaturedIndustryVC" bundle:Nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objFeaturedIndustryVC];
   [revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

Comment: CONTINUE.........     and on viewdidload of frontviewcontroller i  have used this-   SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
      [revealController panGestureRecognizer];
     [revealController tapGestureRecognizer];

Comment: used this

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"your table view object"])
    return NO;
else
    return YES;
}